# Laravel 4 Elequont Tutorial & Examples

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying out laravel 4 after using codeigniter. I am really impressed with the Eloquent ORM but i need practical examples of the advanced features. I can't find any other than just simple implementations. For example, I need to fetch posts grouped into categories like

```
Games
     Post 1
     Post 2
Movies
     Post 5
     Post 7
....
....
```

How can i do this easily with Eloquent? Examples on scope & collections will be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (Group::with('posts')->get() as $group)
{
    $posts = $group->posts;
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You may want to consider the documentation on eager loading:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent